# Combine multiple onTouchListeners()

Tags: android, listview, ontouchlistener

I have an `Activity`, inside is [`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) and inside is [`ListFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html) with [`ListView`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) items. I want define touch gesture for the items (drag, fling etc.).

I'm able to attach [`onTouchListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) to each `ListView` item `View` by overriding `getView()` of adapter.

```
Adapter adapter = new Adapter(blah, blah, blah) {
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View itemView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            itemView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                blah, blah, blah
            });
            return itemView;
        }
     };
```

But I only receive [`MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_DOWN), [`MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_MOVE) and [`MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_UP) if it occurs inside triggering item `View` boundary. For example I'm not able to catch [`MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_OUTSIDE).

My guess is, that my custom `onTouchListener` compete with listener of `ViewPager` and of `Activity`. I want to trigger these other listeners in some occasions, i.e. if user move to side, I want to slide the whole `View` inside `ViewPager` but if he push on the `ListView` item and move vertically, I want [`startDrag()`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html) of the item.

How to implement that?

---

**Edit/** Currently, my custom listener on `ListView` items works along with `ViewPager`, which is great. I'm able to catch `ListView` item events as long as I don't move outside its `View` and I'm able to slide the whole `View` in `ViewPager` as well.

---

**Edit/** I've rewrote my `ListView` into `RecycledView` and realized that if I attach listener to item `View`, the `ViewPager` catches almost all move events, while allowing only the click events to go through. I've also realized, that if I attach `OnTouchListener` to the `RecycledList` it *is* able to catch move events along with the `ViewPager` so it depends on which level I attach the `Listener`. Problem is, that in item `View` level I have available full reference to item, while when working with the list, I need to guess item position from event coordinates and then gather data from Adapter and `RecycledView`, which is extra work.

---

**Edit/** it wasn't that hard after all. Luckily, `RecycledView` has `findChildViewUnder(int xPos, int yPos)` method, so getting the `View` was piece of cake.

Here's my implementation, if someone is interested

```
    mRecycledView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        int LONG_PRESS_TIMEOUT = ViewConfiguration.getLongPressTimeout();
        float mItemViewHeight, mInitialY;
        boolean mIsResolved;
        final Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        final Runnable mLongPress = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mIsResolved = true;
                onLongClick();
            }
        };
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {
            switch (MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(me)) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    mInitialY = me.getY();
                    mActiveUserView = mRecycledView.findChildViewUnder(me.getX(), mInitialY);
                    if (mActiveUserView == null) { // clicked to RecycledView where's no item
                        mIsResolved = true;
                    } else {
                        mIsResolved = false;
                        mItemViewHeight = (float) mActiveUserView.getHeight();
                        mHandler.postDelayed(mLongPress, LONG_PRESS_TIMEOUT);
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (!mIsResolved) {
                        stopLongClickHandler();
                        // check for vertical upward move
                        if (mInitialY - me.getY() > mItemViewHeight) {
                            mIsResolved = true;
                            onVerticalDrag();
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (!mIsResolved) {
                        stopLongClickHandler();
                        mIsResolved = true;
                        onClick();
                    }
            }
            return !mIsResolved;
        }

        void stopLongClickHandler() {
            mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        }

        void onVerticalDrag() {
            Log.e("DEBUG", "start drag");
        }

        void onLongClick() {
            Log.e("DEBUG", "long click");
        }

        void onClick() {                
            Log.e("DEBUG", "short click");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest you replacing `ListView` with `RecyclerView`. Then read [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf#.98u5i95ix): it contains almost every drag/swipe/touch implementations on `RecyclerView` clearly explained.

Comment: The tutorial is awesome, but did not helped me in my task. It describes how to easily reposition or fling to remove item in the list. What I try to achieve is perform remove by dragging item up onto button in [`Toolbar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html).

Comment: then you need to set-up a drag listener to your button and implement corresponding behavior